# ng-repeat not working when i use constant

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, constants

Im new at AngularJS.

I have to make dropdown menu from the constants.
Here my code:

```
.constant('COLORS',
    [
        {red: '#ff0000'},
        {green: '#00ff00'},
        {blue: '#0000ff'}
    ]
).directive('colorSetter', ['COLORS', function (COLORS) {
    return {
        scope: {
            user: "="
        },
        restrict: 'E',
        // templateUrl: 'colorSetterDirective.html'
        template: '<select name="mySelect" ng-model="colorModel">' +
        '<option ng-repeat="(key,value) in COLORS">{{c.key}} -  {{c.value}}</option>' +
        '</select>'
    }
```

Then, it creates the dropdown menu, but there is nothing show. Its empty.
I tried everything , but it wont work. I used that line too, but still not working:

```
<option ng-repeat="c in COLORS">{{c}}</option>
```

pic:
[empty selectors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6OEB.jpg)

index.html:

```
....
<td><color-setter ng-model="colors" user="x"></color-setter></td>
```

Thank you Guys!

Edit:
app.js

```
var app = angular.module("testProject", ['ui.router', 'ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize'])
.service('userService', function ($http) {
    this.getUsers = function () {
        return $http.get('users.json');
    };
})
.controller('testProjectCtrl',function ($scope, userService, COLORS) {
    function GetAllUsers() {
        var getUsersData = userService.getUsers();

        getUsersData.then(function (user) {
            $scope.users = user.data;
        }, function () {
            alert('Error in getting user records');
        });
    }

    function init() {
        $scope.sortType = "username";
        $scope.sortReverse = false;
        $scope.limitNumber = 10;
        $scope.colors = COLORS;

    }

    $scope.setDb = function (darab) {
        $scope.limitNumber = darab;
    }
    init();
    GetAllUsers();

}).constant('COLORS',
    [
        {red: '#ff0000'},
        {green: '#00ff00'},
        {blue: '#0000ff'}
    ]
).directive('colorSetter', ['COLORS', function (COLORS) {
    return {
        scope: {
            user: "="
        },
        restrict: 'E',
        // templateUrl: 'colorSetterDirective.html'
        template: '<select name="mySelect" ng-model="colorModel">' +
        '<option ng-repeat="c in COLORS">{{c}}</option>' +
        '</select>'
    }


}]);
```

Comment: You have to bind `COLORS` constant to controller `$scope` to access it on view level..

Comment: Im edited the code, with the full app.js file, please check. Thank you Pankaj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to inject constants in the controller $scope

```
.directive('colorSetter', ['COLORS', function (COLORS) {
    return {
        scope: {
            user: "="
        },
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'colorSetterDirective.html',
        controller:function($scope){
            $scope.colors = COLORS;
        }
    }
}]);
```

colorSetterDirective.html:

```
<select name="mySelect" ng-model="colorModel">
    <option ng-repeat="c in colors">{{c}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank yout DevSullo, now works. I dont knew that, i need to inject COLORS in controller.